# logic - checking if at least one field is not null

Tags: php, forms, file

i have this code, and need help with the logic end.  I would like for at least one field to not be null.

```
if(!empty($fileTypes) || !empty($fileSizes) || !empty($fileUploads) || !empty($features) || !empty($design) || !empty($other) || !empty($contact)) {
} else {
    $error = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes apologies the following works:

```
$array = array();

if($_POST){

        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
            if (!empty($value)){
                $array[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
        if (empty($array))
        {
        echo 'array empty';//throw error
        } else {
            echo 'array not empty'; //there is a submission
        }
}
```

EDIT: Missed a closing tag in the paste....fixed

Comment: but i enter nothing in the form, and have this code, and it returns good... if($_POST){
echo "good";
} else {
$error = 1;
}

Comment: i think it's taking in the submit button, even when all my other fields are empty, and returning that there were values entered.

Comment: when i print out the key in the foreach/if loop, i get submit.

Comment: fixed: foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
            if (!empty($value) && $key != "submit"){
                $array[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
  
        if (empty($array))
        {
        echo 'error';//throw error
  $error = 1;
        } else {
            echo 'good'; //there is a submission
        }

Comment: It is showing because you have given your submit button a 'name="submit"' attribute. If you take this away you will not need the extra logic and your code will be cleaner.

Comment: the post will only run on form submit, right?  because for some reason, it is automatically running the code, like the form has been submitted...

Comment: If you are hitting 'refresh' and the browser is saying resubmit, then yes it will repost, however if you just navigate to the page then it wont. This is another issue though.....once you have parsed the form then use header() to redirect back to the page to prevent this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9602/discussion-between-droidus-and-zac)